# How to find x from expression?

Tags: equation-solving

I need to find x in this expression

x(2x + 5) = 168

I have already tried to move x from one side to another with brackets and without them,

Like this

x = 168; 2x + 5 = 168 , 2x = 163 , x = 81.5......

but anyway eventually without success...

I know that the answer is x = 8;

But I can't come to this solution...

How to solve this?

Comment: Did you want to ask on math.stackexchange.com?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this does not seem to be a question about how to use the Wolfram software product *Mathematica*.

Comment: This is a quadratic equation. You can try to solve it in your mind. At first you write it in the form $ax^2+bx+c=0$, that is $2x^2+5x-168=0$. Next, you have 2 solutions: $\frac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}=\frac{-5\pm\sqrt{5^2+4\cdot2\cdot168}}{4}=\frac{5\pm37}{4}$. Then the two solutions are $8$ and $-10.5$.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
Solve[x(2 x+5)==168,x]
(*{{x -> -(21/2)}, {x -> 8}}*)
```

Comment: I did not understand what do you write... Could you please simplify it?

Comment: Perhaps now is a good time for you to read the documentaion of `Solve`